# GCD Discrepancy in Apple docs on concurrent queue creation

Tags: cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

[The Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) says this:

> You cannot create concurrent dispatch queues yourself. Instead, there are three global concurrent queues for your application to use.

Then the [GCD Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW57) says this:

> ```
> dispatch_queue_create()
> ```
>
> In OS X v10.7 and later, specify `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` (or `NULL`) to create a serial queue or **specify `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` to create a concurrent queue.**

This is a bit confusing; it implies you can indeed create a concurrent queue yourself; is it a case of the docs not being updated to explain current features?

Comment: I would guess that the first piece of documentation is outdated. Note that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` is only available since iOS 5.0, and GCD was introduced in iOS 4.0. The Concurrency Programming Guide was probably written at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you link to are saying that on iOS you can only create serial queues. On OSX you can create serial or concurrent queues.

This appears to be out of date since iOS5..
(Thanks to @omz and @Analog File)

Comment: thanks for changing your answer to reflect this. it is however still confusing that the second doc still says `Available in iOS 4.0 and later.` yet you and @omz are suggesting it is iOS5 only

Comment: Feel free to file a documentation bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com/.   The documentation team is extremely responsive.

Comment: @andrewx - sorry for the confusion, you can indeed create your own dispatch queues on iOS as of iOS 4, the docs are correct in that regard.
On OSX you had the extra ability to configure a custom queue so that work items added to the queue could be executed fifo or concurrently. iOs didn't have this extra configuration option until iOS5 (on iOS4 items defaulted to executing serially, fifo).
Since iOS5, OSX and iOS dispatch queues have feature parity - the Concurrency Programming Guide has not been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It's also important to note that the man pages are a bit outdated even on 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and do not document all the changes to GCD as the API has evolved.  Fortunately, the HeaderDoc comments in the GCD header files themselves have been zealously maintained and remain the definitive reference.  How to use?  Command line to the rescue!

```
% mkdir /tmp/gcd-docs
% headerdoc2html -o /tmp/gcd-docs /usr/include/dispatch
```

Ignore all the scary messages from headerdoc2html and then, once it's finished:

```
% open /tmp/gcd-docs
```

To bring up the finder on the various "chapters" of GCD, descending into each directory with the Finder and then clicking on the Index.html file for each category of the API you want more information on. This will also give definitive availability information for iOS and OS X on each API function.  HTH!